# Shape Editor - Stereotype - png format - black background

Tags: png, transparency, enterprise-architect, shapescript

I am trying to create UML profiles with custom icon/images.
I understood that in order to show custom icon for my stereotype, I must use shapescript and accordingly this is done.

Now the problem is with the transparency. When I use png file with transparency it shows good in "image manager", but when I use in shape editor, I get black background, and accordingly after importing MDG Technology, the stereotype renders black background.  :(
I am using png format.

Is there any workaround?

Regards
VJ

Answer (score 0):

We have confirmation from Sparx that this is supported in version 13 (which is currently in Beta)
See also http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,31019.msg225007.html